# Regex: Allow all characters except four, restriction including underscore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am not very familiar with regex.

I am trying to implement some restrictions on input. I want to allow all numbers and characters, with special characters like `~"$#*@` etc. except these 4: `& ' % _`.

I tried like:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9\-!@#\$\^*\)\(+=.-\~\"]/
```

But it is not restricting the `_` underscore. How can I restrict underscore, and is there any best way to allow all except 4 without writing all symbols in regex?

Comment: Right here you have a range: `.-\~` (index 46-126) and that range includes underscore (index 95). See for yourself at https://regex101.com/r/NRe2Fj/1

Comment: I would say that is easier to negate the few exceptions with tilde operator `/[^&'%_\s]/` rather than list all allowed ones (\s for spaces)

Comment: @buzatto Presumably the disallow list would also need to include chars from other languages. In comparison, the allow list will be considerably shorter. I'm sure one could also figure out the range for 46-94 and 96-126.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your range `.-\~` (index 46-126) includes underscore (index 95). So you can either figure out what chars are 46-94 and 96-126 or use a lookahead to omit the undesired chars:

```
(?=[^&'%_])[a-zA-Z0-9\-!@#\$\^*\)\(+=.-\~\"]
```

https://regex101.com/r/rV0gxb/1

---

You can also negate like this is it's easier to read:

```
(?![&'%_])[a-zA-Z0-9\-!@#\$\^*\)\(+=.-\~\"]
```